# Find doc ids before query phase?

Tags: elasticsearch

As we do any search in elastic, Elastic performs it in two phases i.e Query and fetch phase as explained under section "Default search type: Query Then Fetch" at this [resource](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch)

Here are the points

1. Send the query to each shard
2. Find all matching documents and calculate scores using local Term/Document Frequencies
3. Build a priority queue of results (sort, pagination with from/to, etc)
   ..

I have a question on point 1 of query phase. Per my understanding before query phase itself, elastic will find the relevant documents ids from inverted index based on the word in search query.
Then query will go specific shards only instead of going to each shard.  Is that correct ?

So in query phase will elastic fetch those documents from shard based on document_id got grom inverted index, then calculate the scores for fetched document and return id's along with scrores to requesting node.

In fetch phase requesting node get all scores and decide what needs to sent to client then it actually fetches the document.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question on point 1 of query phase. Per my understanding
>   before query phase itself, elastic will find the relevant documents
>   ids from inverted index based on the word in search query. Then query
>   will go specific shards only instead of going to each shard. Is that
>   correct ?

Here elastic will identify the shard based on document id before query phase. Inverted index does not come into the picture here. Once query goes to shard, the elastic refers the inverted index to find which term exists in which file/index.

Rest of the stuff is same as you pointed in mentioned resource